# String to Date SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, date, datetime, oracle11g

I have a `Comments (Clob)` field which is a collection of the time the comment was made, comment made by and the comment itself.

I need to extract the 'Date', 'Comment by' from the field.

Using Regular expressions, I was able to extract the date fields and comment_by field but the date is in character.

I'm not able to convert this field into `Date`.

Comments Example:

> *7/18/2018 10:36:29 AM*, *beginj* requesting cancellation as steps are no longer viable.
>
> *5/16/2018 8:28:04 AM*, *josephav* Not applicable for GSC

I can get the 'date' using this regular expression (RE):

```
regexp_substr((dbms_lob.substr(requestcommentsdisplay,50,1)),'[^ ]+',1)
```

I can get the Comment_by name using this regular expression (RE)

```
regexp_substr((dbms_lob.substr(requestcommentsdisplay,50,1)),'[a-z]+',1)
```

So the dates after I extract using RE are like below:

```
10/5/2017
4/2/2012
12/31/2015
3/16/2014
```

I need to convert these into Proper dates so that I can use these further in my code

Any Help is appreciated :)

Thanks

Comment: You can use [`TO_DATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm)

Comment: ORA-01843: not a valid month

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
   SELECT 
   CASE WHEN (length(<regex_string>). 
     <9)
  Then 
TO_DATE('0'||<regex_string>,'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

> but oracle parses it with single digit as  well though you can
>   try to debug and print dates for single digit via this
>   condition.

```
   ELSE
TO_DATE(<regex_string>,'MM/DD/YYYY') 
    END CASE FROM TABLE;
```

to convert the string to date format as the o/p you got from `regex_substr` is a string.

This will allow you to read the input in the format you are receiving and will convert to actual oracles date format.

Comment: Thanks Himanshu, but I get the following error: ORA-01843: not a valid month

Comment: then check yr data you are having month as single digit at most places so use case statement to join an extra `M` as value `0` with `CASE` statement

Answer (score 0):

You can set nls_territory parameter depending on your country, before calling the query

```
alter session set nls_territory = 'AMERICA';--alternatively convert to 'TURKEY' as an example
```

and then try the following

```
with tab(date_chr) as
(
 select '10/5/2017'  from dual union all
 select '4/2/2012'   from dual union all
 select '12/31/2015' from dual union all
 select '3/16/2014'  from dual  
)
select to_date(date_chr,'MM/DD/YYYY')
  from tab;
```